# A problem of norm linear space with linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $T$ be a linear transformation on real vector space $\Bbb R^n$ over $\Bbb R$ such that $T^2 = \lambda T$ for some $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. Then

1. $||Tx|| = |\lambda| ||x||$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$
2. If $||Tx|| = ||x||$ for some non zero vector $x \in R^n$, then $\lambda = \pm 1$
3. $T = \lambda I$ where $I$ is identity transformation on $\Bbb R^n$.
4. If $||Tx||>||x||$ for some non zero vector $x \in \Bbb R^n$, then $T$ is necessarily singular.

My Attempt:

I think that $\Bbb R^n$ is vector space over $\Bbb R$ with Inner product. So it is a problem of Inner product space.

Option 1, I take $T = \pmatrix {2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}$ such that $T^2 = \pmatrix {2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0} \pmatrix {2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0} = \pmatrix {4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0} = 2\pmatrix {2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0} = 2T$
and $x = \pmatrix {0 \\1} \neq 0$ such that $Tx = \pmatrix {2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}\pmatrix {0 \\1} = \pmatrix {0 \\0}$ Now $||Tx|| = 0 \neq 2||x||$. So option 1 is not true.

Option 4, take $T = 2I \implies T^2 = (2I)(2I) = 4I = 2(2I) = 2T$ Here $||Tx|| = 2||x|| > ||x||$, $x \neq 0$ but $T$ is non singular. So option 4 is not true.

Option 2, we know that If  $T^2 = T$ then $T$ will be unitary and eigen value of unitary transformation of unit modulus. Also $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ so $\lambda = \pm1$ Hence option 2 is true. But I'm not sure that this method is correct.

Option 3. Take $T = \pmatrix {2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0}$ with $T^2 = 2T$ but $T \neq 2I$. So option 3 is false. Please help me in all the four options. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your conclusions about options 1, 3  and 4 are pretty right. 
   You can use the example in your step 1 to prove that options 2 is  incorrect.

   Let $n=2$ and $T=\left[\begin{matrix}2&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right]$, then $T^2=2T$ (i.e., $\lambda=2$). Let $\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}
      1\\\sqrt{3}
   \end{matrix}\right]$, then $T\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}
      2\\0
   \end{matrix}\right]$, so that $\|T\mathbf{x}\|=\|\mathbf{x}\|$, but $\lambda =2$, so option 2 is wrong.
   If you have a good knowledge about functional analysis and operator theory, then the exercise is easy.

Comment: No, half part of option 2 is assumed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you said.

Comment: I said that "If $||Tx|| = ||x||$ for some non zero vector $x \in R^n$" is assumed then we have to find the conditions on $\lambda$

Comment: It's possible that $\lambda=0$ or $|\lambda |\geq 1$ (and only the two cases, use operator theory). For example, let $n=2$.
 (1) $\lambda=0$: $T=\left[\begin{matrix}0&0\\1&0\end{matrix}\right]$, $\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}
    1\\0 
 \end{matrix}\right]$; 
 (2) $|\lambda| \geq 1$: $T= \left[\begin{matrix}
    \lambda&0\\0& 0
 \end{matrix}\right]$, $\mathbf{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}
    1\\\sqrt{\lambda^2-1}
 \end{matrix}\right]$.

Comment: Please tell me that option 2 is right or wrong.

Comment: I have written it in the first comment. It is wrong.

Comment: I'm surprising to see that all options are false. This question is asked in standard exam "CSIR NET June 2011" as it is, that I posted.